# Как сделать такое выравнивание текста?

Tags: html, css

Выглядит это вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т. е. если заголовок короткий, то текст "User added" выравнивается по низу изображения. Но как только заголовок становится длиннее, текст понемногу начинает спускаться.

Как это реализовать? Пробовал обернуть текст с заголовком в блок и задать тексту абсолютное позиционирование, но получается не то.

Comment: браузер это делает автоматически

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь как он это может делать автоматически?

Comment: Почему ссылку на сайт не привели?

Comment: @Alex78191 это не сайт, а просто шаблон

Comment: @Byulent тогда ссылку на шаблон

Comment: @Alex78191 https://s.tmimgcdn.com/scr/21300/21304-original.jpg

Comment: Я про файл шаблона говорил

Comment: @Alex78191 имели в виду PSD? Этого нет

Comment: Я думал, что это шаблон для WordPress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задайте минимальную высоту заголовку.

Без примера кода, могу предложить вот такой вариант:

*(`.item:after` не нужен, добавила для наглядности)*

```css
*, ::after, ::before {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.item{
  position:relative;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  border:1px solid #aaa;
  margin:0 0 1rem;
}
.item:after{
  content:'минимальная высота заголовка';
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  background:#000;
  color:red;
  opacity:.3;
  padding:2rem;
  height:6rem;
  text-align:center;
}
.info{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex:0 0 50%;
  max-width:50%;
  padding:1rem;
}
.photo{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
 align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex:0 0 50%;
  max-width:50%;
  padding:1rem;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  background:orange;
}
.caption{
  flex: 1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size:1.2rem;
  font-weight:bold;
  min-height:6rem;
}
.link{
  color:blue;
  text-decoration:undeline;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="info">
    <div class="caption">заголовок</div>
    <div class="link">ссылка</div>
  </div>
  <div class="photo">фото</div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="info">
    <div class="caption">длинный <br>заголовок</div>
    <div class="link">ссылка</div>
  </div>
  <div class="photo">фото</div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="info">
    <div class="caption">очень <br>длинный <br>заголовок</div>
    <div class="link">ссылка</div>
  </div>
  <div class="photo">фото</div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="info">
    <div class="caption">очень <br>очень <br>очень <br>длинный <br>заголовок</div>
    <div class="link">ссылка</div>
  </div>
  <div class="photo">фото</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Догадался до этого сам, но всё равно спасибо.

Comment: Можно то, что сверху обернуть в отдельный div и задать max-height и для заголовка min-height